# Can downloaded BBC iPlayer content be replayed abroad?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

If I have downloaded BBC programmes from iPlayer on to my computer, will the different broadcast standards between the UK and US prevent their being successfully played on a US TV using HDMI?

Comment: What format are the downloaded programmes in? We have to know that, marking this question as 'unclear', please edit to provide lots of detail, thanks.

Comment: Probably your biggest issue is that iplayer downloads are normally only valid for a short period of time before they expire, and you won't be able to re-download when you're outside the UK....

Comment: If I were british would use a VPN with an exit point in the UK and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the official BBC application to do this, yes, you can watch programs you've already downloaded even when you're overseas. See official guidance:
http://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/tv/watch_outside_uk

You cannot download any further programs, and the programs you've downloaded will only remain for 30 days. This is checked via IP. The idea presumably being that a UK resident (with a current TV license) can download shows and watch them while on holiday.

HDMI is just the method by which you connect your TV to your computer, what you see on the TV is a mirror of your computer screen, and there's no difference between UK and US TVs in that way. So if you have a laptop on which a program was downloaded, and you plug it directly into a TV with HDMI to watch, that should work.